# (keyup.enter) event not working in iOS keypad

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have developed the app in the ionic framework + angular, and for some functionality I have bind (keyup.enter) event with input. but somehow it is not working in the iOS device latest version. but working fine with the older version of iOS device like (OS 12.5.4).

please help me out from this issue.

Ionic Information
[image]

semple source code

```
<ion-input placeholder="Lot Code" [(ngModel)]="txtLotCode" (keyup.enter)="searchItemLotWS()" type="text"> </ion-input>
```

Reference Image

[image]

Comment: I imagine all your buttons has `type="button"` (in Angular all the buttons are "submit buttons")

Answer (score 3):

I have replaced (keyup.enter) event with (keydown.enter) and it works for me,
now **"return"** button is worked for me in the latest iOS (ios 14).

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is, from iOS version 13 onwards, iPhone keyboard ⇧(Shift/Capitalize) button is  auto activated hence pressed key becomes Shift+Enter.

I won't recommend using `(keydown.enter)` because if user keep the enter key pressed it will keep executing the code.

Instead, you can use **autocapitalize** attribute:
`<ion-input **autocapitalize="none"** placeholder="Lot Code" [(ngModel)]="txtLotCode" (keyup.enter)="searchItemLotWS()" type="text"> </ion-input>`.

and

Since, you are using ionic framework, instead of using **ion-input** you can use `<ion-searchbar (search)="searchItemLotWS()"></ion-searchbar>` that works with enter and shift+enter.

Comment: (search) event is not fired in IOS 14.2 beta release. Any insights on this?

Answer (score -1):

what did you try? Can you show the code for us. I try bellow sample and it work.

For html

```
    <ion-input #Field1 (keyup)="gotoNextField(Field2)" </ion-input>
    <ion-input #Field2 (keyup)="gotoNextField(Field3)" </ion-input>
    <ion-input #Field3 (keyup)="gotoNextField(Field4)" </ion-input>
    <ion-input #Field4 (keyup)="finishFunction()" </ion-input>
```

For ts

```
gotoNextField(nextElement)
  nextElement.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: This will not only target the "Enter" key plus it won't work on his IOS version.